# Flutter: how to add anchored button at the bottom of a page after a ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

This is my code until now, I would like to anchor the Material button to the bottom of the Screen, so I would like that my Column to take all the available space on the screen, I cannot use the Scaffold arguments like bottomsheet for this, since it is another widget and there is some separate logic that requires the button to be in the same place as the listView

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column(children[
    Container(),
    Container(),
    _myWidget(),
]));
```

```
Widget _myWidget(){
return Expanded(
  child: Column(
    children:[
      Container(),
      ListView.builder( /* more_code*/ ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: MaterialButton(/* more_code */)
      ),],),
);
```

This is how the button is now, I want to anchor it to the bottom
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write with stack instead of column

```
Widget _myWidget(){
return Expanded(
  child: Stack(
    children:[
      Container(),
      ListView.builder( /* more_code*/ ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: MaterialButton(/* more_code */)
      ),],),
);
```